# Behaviour of django order_by

Tags: django, sql-order-by

I have 3 models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class StudentDriver(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Car(models.Model):
    student_driver = models.ForeignKey(StudentDriver, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Why is it, that if I do the following, the `order_by` is not honoured (my qs will not be ordered by the student_driver.parent_id)? And is there a way I can get it ordered? I need it for a groupby.

```
for car in Car.objects.order_by('student_driver__parent'):
    print(car.student_driver.parent)
```

If I do:

```
for car in Car.objects.order_by('student_driver'):
    print(car.student_driver)
```

it works no problem (the qs is ordered by student_driver_id). Seems to be the ForeignKey link, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It works: you order on the *primary key* (so the `id`) of the `parent` of the `student_driver`.

Comment: But this looks like the XY-problem, can you first specify *what* problem you want to solve, instead of *how* you want to solve it.

Comment: But it's not, the output could be `1, 3, 2, 4`.

Comment: What if you `print(car.student_driver.parent_id)` (so with `_id`?)

Comment: The same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it works:

```
for car in Car.objects.all().order_by('student_driver__parent__id'):
    print(car.student_driver.parent.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works; though I still am unsure as to why.

Surely `student_driver__parent__id` == `student_driver__parent_id`?

Also you don't need the `.all()`

Comment: you should use double underline in django orm, in order to call a field of model

Comment: But `parent_id` will return the Parent object's ID, yes?

Comment: parent__id is cirrect

Comment: I understand that, I'm just trying to understand why ordering by `parent_id` is different from `parent__id`